# Universal windows platform - Consuming web service, ASMX (Content type parsing)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, uwp

I'm getting started with UWP and wish to consume an old, heavily used ASMX web service written in VB.Net 2.0.

I have created a service reference to the web service but whatever function I call I always end up with the error

"An exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: MessageEncoder content type parsing is not supported."

There's no further help than this, not sure if it's because the return type is XML and it's expecting JSON or something, even if that were the case I see nowhere to change this.

Here is the relevant lines that I am using to pull back a simple response, help would be greatly appreciated.

```
WSSoapClient proxy = new WSSoapClient();
Guid ProviderGUID = Guid.Parse("[REDACTED]");
string ProviderPassword = "[REDACTED]";
objWSEthnicitiesGetReturn result;
result = await proxy.WSEthnicitiesGetAsync(ProviderGUID, ProviderPassword);
```

Comment: this exception may be caused by NetworkCredentials object set in System.Net.HttpClient - it is not supported on UWP, you can use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient and PasswordCredential instead.

Comment: I think we'd need to know a bit more of the architecture of the service before we can know what's going on here. Is it WCF? A WCF subset like data services? What namespace are you getting your WSSoapClient from, is it from the service reference? If not, it should be. Is your service definitely using SOAP?

Comment: It is hard to know the reason with only these few line code. It will be much better if you can provide a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproduce project.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, while the W/S is using HTTP... during use the endpoint was changed to HTTP.  Now while there is a redirect in IIS this caused the lookup to always return a 301 error.

In the reference file for the Service Reference I had to alter the proc GetBindingForEndpoint to include the following lines

```
result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.None;
result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
```

Whilst bringing the reference into the project .NET had also changed all references to the HTTPS to HTTP so I had to do a search for all instances throughout the project and manually change them all.

All is good now though so thank you for your time guys.