# AMSX Web Service

Tags: uwp, asmx

I have create 2 project to test the web service.

One of the project is the asmx

```
 namespace KioskWS
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for WebService
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/KioskWS/WebService.asmx")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
        {
            [WebMethod]
            public string HelloWorld()
            {
                return "Hello World";
            }
        }
    }
```

The second project is the main. It is using Universal Windows and does not have the Add Web Reference. How do i call the web service to display hello world in a messagebox to test? The code below can't work. Please help!

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            KioskWS.HelloWorldResponse ws = new KioskWS.HelloWorldResponse();
            string message = ws.ToString();
            MessageDialog clickMessage = new MessageDialog(message);
            clickMessage.ShowAsync();

        }
```

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743255/universal-windows-platform-consuming-web-service-asmx-content-type-parsing

Comment: By the way.... is this a Windows 8.x universal app? Or a Windows 10 universal app? Which sdk are you targetting?

Comment: Windows 10 Universal App. Now i am trying to test the web service but unable to get Hello World in a message box

Answer (score 0):

I have not used an ASMX in a while, but should this:

```
KioskWS.HelloWorldResponse ws = new KioskWS.HelloWorldResponse();
string message = ws.ToString();
```

not be something like this:

```
KioskWS.WebService ws = new KioskWS.WebService();
string message = ws.HelloWorld();
```

Perhaps rename the webservice class on the asmx side to make it easier to read/understand.

Comment: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) for the second one

Comment: The first one can used but it display KioskWS.HelloWordResponse in a message box

Answer (score 0):

> It is using Universal Windows and does not have the Add Web Reference.

You need to "Add Service Reference" in a UWP app. Right-click the UWP project and choose "Add Service Reference".
And discover the web services in current solution and select the one you want to reference, provide a namespace name (for example `KioskWS`).

[image]

And then you could invoke the web service in UWP app. For example, invoking the `HellowWorld` and show the body text should like follows:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   KioskWS.WebServiceSoapClient client = new KioskWS.WebServiceSoapClient();
   HelloWorldResponse test = await client.HelloWorldAsync();
   string message = test.Body.HelloWorldResult;
   MessageDialog clickMessage = new MessageDialog(message);
   await clickMessage.ShowAsync(); 
}
```

Additionally, I recommend you to use WCF service instead since "ASP.NET Web Services" (aka ASMX) is a legacy technology. Details you may reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023487/asp-net-web-service-template-not-exist/24983942#24983942).